# Viewing SQL Server query from .NET application and from SSAS cube

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, ssas

I am working on an ASP.NET MVC app and the database is a SQL Server Analysis Services (SSAS) cube. This application was developed 3 years ago and there is no documentation - but it's working. However the application needs to change a lot now because of new requirements.

I am new to this field and I need to figure out the SQL query which is generated during the application at runtime. I tried to figure out by debugging but I am stuck. I could view the SQL query.

So, if anybody tells me the way to see the SQL query then I can easily debug and figure out the SQL query. Again I am telling you this is really new for me and I am struggling for the last two days to figure it out.

If you can share the way to get the actual SQL query, then it really helps me a lot!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQL Profiler to connect to your Analysis Instance and see the query being executed.

You get access to the SQL Profiler by installing the SQL Managemt Tools. The queries being used are going to be either MDX or DAX queries depending on what type of Analysis Services you're using.

The Query Begin Event will show you the query being used.

Comment: can you please share some more details. or some references to follow

Comment: I installed SQL Management Tools and opened the SQL profiler. Can you plz tell me which events do i need to choose. I only need the genereated sql query which is generated by the .net mvc applicaion

Comment: @adarksun try the Query Begin Event.

Comment: Hi I see, I do not have permission to trace as I am getting the error like "errors in the metada manager. either the trace with the ID of 'someString' does not exist in the server with the id 'dbName' or the user does not have permissions to access the object". So, is there any other way to see the query?

Comment: Your other option would be to go back and try debugging. I know you said you got stuck doing that before but I would try again and find where the call to the database is done.

Comment: @ Ola Ekdahl: by debugging I see the actual data values just before it is printing to the UI. But I could not figure out the actual sql queries. Do you have any suggestions that I am missing every time. Or to follow the way to figure out. Thanks

Comment: Since it's a MVC app I would look for the View generating the output and work my way back. Find the Controller and Action calling that View. In the Action there's going to be code creating a new Model instance and population that Model with data from the database. Figuring out how that Model or collection of Models are created should do the trick. I would guess that there's going to be a Data Access Layer component involved somewhere in the app as well.